# No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

When I m trying to compile my app it is showing `[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.`

But when I run it shows-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter
doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.27.0-5.0.pre.94, on
    Linux, locale C.UTF-8)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find
    Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting
      CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✗] Flutter IDE Support (No supported IDEs
    installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Byw I m using VS Code but on termux and I m new to flutter and this is my first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variable under system variables.
You also need to restart the android studio after setting system variable.

For ex.

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = "C:\Android\SDK"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for Ubuntu. Change the path to your SDK directory.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
```

This is for windows. Change the path to your SDK directory.

```
set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="C:\installation location\android-sdk"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows. Change the path to your SDK directory.

on windows

set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="C:\installation location\android-sdk"

on linux
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk